# Facebook share URL Not working in mobile Devices

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have used following URL to share a URL of my website

```
https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com
```

It is working well in desktop. but while share this in mobile devices it doesnot share on facebook, it redirected to following URL

```
https://m.facebook.com/a/sharer.php?shouldRedirectToPermalink=1&isthrowbackpost
```

I tried lot but i cont find solutions, Could any one help me to find issues

Comment: How are you using the url? In a link? Are you adding any other parameters to the request or is https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com exactly what you are passing? 
Copying and pasting the above into the url bar works as expected and shared to facebook.

Comment: It happens only  in mobile devices @Hey Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and the way I solved it was to make sure that the Facebook `app_id` in the share URL on mobile was the same my Facebook `app_id`. That fixed it for me.

In my case, there was a Wordpress plugin that was putting in a different `app_id` in the share URL, and my guess was that Facebook didn't like that there were 2 different IDs.

Also, I found this Chrome extension very helpful for changing the HTTP headers to simulate a mobile device so that I could test whether it would work on mobile from my desktop.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj